# conditions for multiple variables in while loop c++

Tags: c++, while-loop

Im trying to get my while loop to show "Invalid input" For a while loop for 3 variables.
Im just starting out with c++ so im not the best at trying to show what i need but here it is in my terms.

```
while(children1,children2,children3)<1||(children1,children2,children3)>100)
 cout << "invalid input"; return 0;
```

Comment: learn about the comma expression syntax and logic shorted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's probably easiest to to express each requirement separately:

```
while (children1 < 1 || children2 < 1 || children3 < 1 ||
       children1 > 100 || children2 > 100 || children3 > 100)
    std::cout << "invalid input\n";
```

A C++11 alternatives is:

```
#include <algorithm>

...

while (std::min({ children1, children2, children3 }) < 1 ||
       std::max({ children1, children2, children3 }) > 100)
    std::cout << "invalid input\n";
```

FWIW, if you kept the numbers in a `std::vector` another - arguably more elegant - option would be available:

```
std::vector<int> children;
children.push_back(23);
children.push_back(123);
children.push_back(13);
// ...however many you like...

while (std::any_of(std::begin(children), std::end(children), 
                   [](int n) { return n < 1 || n > 100; }))
    std::cout << "invalid input\n";
```

---

Note too that if you intend multiple instructions to be controlled by a statement like `while`, `if`, or `for`, you need to group them using braces:

```
int retries_available = 3;
while (std::any_of(std::begin(children), std::end(children), 
                   [](int n) { return n < 1 || n > 100; }))
{
    std::cout << "invalid input\n";
    if (retries_available-- == 0)
        return 0;
    get_new_values_for(children);
}
```

Comment: @TonyD: shouldn't the `while` be an `if`?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I'm guessing the OP intends to put some other statement into the loop to get new values for the `children` vars.  If not, your comment may help him or her (not sure which of the two people in the profile pic it is!).

Comment: i would've used an if statement but, my prof requested a while loop. Terrible i know.